# timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, database, nosql

I have seen this problem at many forums but none of them resolved my issue. I am trying to insert a sample document to MongoDB DB. Unfortunately, during the insert process `colReceived.insert(doc)` I got following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
>   com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
>   waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view
>   of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017,
>   type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
>   exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
>   socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect}}]    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)

Here is my connectToDb method

```
   MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

    // Now connect to your database
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    System.out.println("connect to database successfully");

    DBCollection coll = db.createCollection("mycol", null);
    System.out.println("Collection created successfully");

    DBCollection colReceived = db.getCollection("mycol");
    System.out.println("Collection mycol selected successfully");

    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "MongoDB").append("description", "database").append("likes", 100)
            .append("url", "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/").append("by", "tutorials point");

    colReceived.insert(doc);
    System.out.println("Document inserted successfully");
```

My pom.xml :

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.objectdb.tutorial.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>Guestbook</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Guestbook</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>objectdb</id>
        <name>ObjectDB Repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.objectdb.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.objectdb.Enhancer</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>guest.Guest</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>Guestbook</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Yes isha many months ago i resolved it myself

Comment: How did you resolve it? Canyou plz answer your question and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

If you also have the following error in your mongod logs... (or similar)

> ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files Please make at least
>   3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles

You can fix this error by running mongo as `mongod --smallfiles`

Otherwise, try updating your mongo-driver version to match that of the server you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, in my case I was using Atlas MongoDB and my ISP was rotating IP pool for clients at random time intervals.

So I've had the same error and the solution was adding actual IP address to the IP whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

Had the `same exception` in my case when I was trying to perform `update` on Mongo collection.

The issue on my case was that I was using `replica sets` and the connection string was pointing to `Secondary cluster`. Due to this, I was able to read from the cluster but was unable to perform write(insert, update) operations. So, changing the connection string to point `Primary Cluster` fixed this issue for me.